# asp.net checkbox

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview pulling back data from a table in my SQL database. I have a checkbox field in my database set to BIT data value. I need to be able to select a row from the table in asp.net (only one at a time) in order to accept or decline a purchase order.

So far i have the following code

```
<asp:CheckBoxField DataField="CheckBox" HeaderText="Select" Visible="true" ReadOnly="false" />
```

which is just pulling back the fact that the column "checkbox" has a checkbox value and not allowing me to select it. All of the demonstrations i have seen of this have been using the datagrid view and inserting a checkbox into there, however, i cant seem to add the fields from my database to this.

Any help welcome

Answer (score 0):

The gridview defaults to `ItemMode` where it does not allow editing. You'll have to add an edit command and switch to `EditMode` and then your check box should be editable.

```
 <Columns>
       ...
       <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
       ...
 </Columns>
```

Alternatively, you can make it a `TemplateField` and make it editable even in `ItemMode`.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design as, despite being a checkbox field, the rows in a GridView are uneditable by default.  The way I've always handled this is with a [`TemplateField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.aspx):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkSelect" Checked='<%# Eval("Select") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then, if you want to only select one row at a time, use something like this (in [jQuery 1.6](http://jquery.com/)):

```
var checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"][name$="chkSelect"]');
checkboxes.click(function() {
    checkboxes.not(this).prop("checked", false);
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/wsSh5/)