# Get selector in event handler

Tags: jquery

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469116/asp-net-checkbox/6469251#6469251) with this jQuery code:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name$="chkSelect"]').click(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"][name$="chkSelect"]').not(this).prop("checked", false);
});
```

... and it got me thinking: there must be a way to avoid duplicating the selector in the event handler.

I tried `$(this).selector` but that just returns an empty string.  [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/Qaj8h/).

**Is there a way to get the selector text in the event handler?**

Comment: you're `$('____').selector` is only returning __, you can try it with anything like `$('abcdefgi").selector`..

Comment: I get the correct selector (div) in your example. (I'm using FF 5)

Comment: @maenu: I think you did not click the element ;)

Comment: @mazlix: I don't know what you mean - in the first example, `div` is returned. In the second (click) example, empty string is returned. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: @Felix Kling: You're sowhat right ;)

Comment: @Town, try `alert($('allyourbasearebelongtous').selector)` and you'll get a popup saying `'allyourbaasearebelongtous'`.. `this`isn't a string so it alerts an empty string.

Comment: @mazlix: That's correct, because in that context `allyourbasearebelongtous` is the selector (although you won't see any elements returned!).  `alert` implicitly calls `toString` on the parameter, so `alert(this)` is the same as `alert(this.toString())`, which displays `[object HTMLDivElement]`.  `alert($(this).selector)`  displays the selector property of a jQuery object created from `this`, but in my demo context it's empty because the underlying element `this` is a DOM element that has no concept of how it was selected. Hope that makes sense! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(this).selector` does not work because you create a **new** jQuery object and pass a DOM element, not a selector.

If you only want to avoid repeating the selector, you can cache the elements beforehand (which is better anyway):

```
var $elements = $('input[type="checkbox"][name$="chkSelect"]');
$elements.click(function() {
    $elements.not(this).prop("checked", false);
});
```

But I don't think there is a way to get the selector *inside* the event handler. The only reference you have to the selected elements is the corresponding DOM element (through `this`). But you cannot "reverse engineer" the selector from that.

Comment: I _knew_ you'd be the one to answer this Felix, cheers :)  I figured the first bit out (`this` is the DOM element) but I thought there might be a 'nice' way to get the selector.  I guess caching it is the next best thing, plus it means less typing which is always good on a Friday afternoon ;)

Comment: @Town: Exactly :) Happy Friday :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always do:

```js
for(var i in arr){
  $(arr[i]).bind('click', {'selector': arr[i]}, function(event){
    console.log(event.data.selector);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').click(function() {
    alert($(this)[0].nodeName);
});
```

Comment: That works if you only select elements based on their name. If you have a more complex selector then you are out of luck. Have a lock at the answer @Tom linked to.

Comment: This is fine as long as the selector directly translates to a node.  If you change the selector to eg: `#myDiv` then it fails.

Answer (score 0):

This guys seems to have done it. [How do I get a jQuery selector's expression as text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500246/how-do-i-get-a-jquery-selectors-expression-as-text/501316#501316) - see Pim Jager's answer

Comment: Cheers Brandon. I did see that, but the line _This is far from optimal but works in some cases_ coupled with the fact it more than a couple of lines long put me off ;)  I reckon the caching option is the best.

Comment: I'm also not sure that it's a duplicate - while the essence of the question is the same, the accepted answer in the above link forms part of my original question - so I'd consider it to be more of a progression than a duplicate! :)

Comment: @Town - Ha, I saw that line too after I posted this. Interesting solution, but yeah 'some cases' is not 'enough cases' from my point of view. Glad you were able to find an acceptable solution!