# How to get all items in jquery list with $(this)?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to refer to original list by this or other variable. Lets say I have code like this:

```
$('input').focus(function(){
    $(this).css('border','solid 10px');
});
```

This will make any input that has focus its border thicker, but I want all inputs border to be thicker when anyone of the inputs has focus that were in the list. I know it can be done by reselecting all inputs, but for **efficiency sake is there any variable that lets you access original jquery list inside event handler.**

Comment: What is the list? Do you mean an `ul` or `ol`?

Comment: You store `$('input')` in a variable and use it in the binding and the css border

Comment: by list i mean list of items that jquery selected with selector i provided.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get selector in event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469807/get-selector-in-event-handler)

Answer (score 2):

You don't do it with `$(this)`. You just store the inputs in a variable at first then do all you need

```
var $inputs = $('input');

$inputs.focus(function(){
    $inputs.css('border','solid 10px');
});
```

Comment: ok yea wow..my brain slow much. anyways still is there no built in variable for jquery?

Comment: Not for what you are trying to do, even when you do `$(this)`, it is still creating a new jquery object. In your case, you just need to cache the inputs